# CSS selector hover not working for list inside a list

Tags: css, html

I'm using the code from the [Homepage Creative page](http://demo.osthemes.biz/wolverine/homepage-creative.html) from [Wolverine's Multipurpose HTML 5 Template](https://themeforest.net/item/wolverine-multipurpose-html5-template/12930598). When I hover over a link in the nav bar, the sub-menu doesn't show up. Is there a way to make the submenu show up? I also noticed that changing `display:none` in `.nav-main-menu > li > ul` does ***not*** show the submenu.

**Inline CSS**

```
  <style> 

    .nav-main-menu > li > ul {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-main-menu > li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
    } 
</style>
```

**External CSS Stylesheet**

```
  .nav-main-menu:not(.left-menu) > .sub-menu > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .nav-main-menu:not(.left-menu) > .sub-menu .sub-menu > ul {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-main-menu:not(.left-menu) > .sub-menu .sub-menu:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.7s;
            animation: fadeIn 0.7s;
  }

  .nav-main-menu:not(.left-menu) > .sub-menu:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.7s;
            animation: fadeIn 0.7s;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav-main-menu nav-content-item">
          <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">PROJECT OVERVIEW</a></li>
              <li><a href="">PROJECT BACKGROUND</a></li>
              <li><a href="">FUTURE APPLICATIONS</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Is there a style declaration for .nav-content-item that might be overriding the one for .nav-main-menu?

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier No, I checked. I updated my answer with more CSS styling that could be possibly overriding the inline styling?

Comment: @Amanda Just looking at your HTML, I see no element with class `.left-menu` (probably not important) or class `.sub-menu` (probably important).

Comment: Can you provide the link to your site?  I don't see anything that looks like it would keep it from working, and clicking on mobile, at least, makes the menu show with the HTML and CSS provided in your question, so there must be something else affecting it.

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier https://amandaong.github.io/WikiWebsite/. The styling is in styles>main.css and the js is in js>main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't your CSS - it's the size of your webpage. :-)  The body does not currently extend past `div class="main-nav-wrapper nav-wrapper-1-creative">`, so the submenu, which is positioned below it, is not visible even when set to `display: block`.  Once you have added the rest of your webpage, the submenus should show up fine.  If you want to see them before then, add a `min-height` to the body to make it taller.